# AndroidStudio always build failed 'Could not delete..'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':wrap:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard'.
> java.io.IOException: Could not delete path 'D:\workplace\myapp\wrap\build\intermediates\classes\release\com\bartoszlipinski'.
```

I know that I can delete files manually. But I have 10 modules.
It often occurs.
Clean task is worked, but clean is slow.

Comment: you can use clear cache/restart option from file menu to do so.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51568314/5305430 for lifetime