# Could not delete path

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-build

I have been facing these **"Could not delete path"** problems for months.

To run my application, I always have to delete all my app/build files.
But it is very **time-consuming**.

Sometimes i have to restart android studio for run my application.

Tried clean project and run. Tried clean project, build project and run. tried Invalidates caches / restart also but my app didn't run until i clear that project build folder.

These are the errors I am getting alternatively.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can I reinstall Android Studio to solve this or is there a solution to get rid of it?

Comment: do you try to delete while your android studio is open?

Comment: yes and sometimes i have to restart android studio for run my application.

Comment: Check the last comment on this question [Android Studio 3 - EOCD Signature not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50448295), it may be the same problem. Also, doing a fresh install of the latest version of Android Studio should not take too liong, it's worth to give it a try.

Comment: @Adinia that would be mine last solution.

Comment: Why? It's not that hard, you can even install another instance of Android Studio in parallel, without uninstalling the actual one. See https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/install-preview

Comment: @Adinia yeah i can. just looking for people who faced same problem and their suggestions thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot delete a file or folder because it is locked by another program.

First You should check out what program is causing the problem. On superuser.com there is already [related topic](https://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows) and there is also a [solution](https://superuser.com/a/399660/70061) with step to step how to do it.

I used to use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to resolve the problem.

Comment: will you tell me why it is lock ? how we unlock it again ?

Comment: In this situation reinstalling Android Studio is not the case. Something is using folder/file at the same time as Android Studio. It's like someone was trying close the drawer when Your hands are inside.

Comment: it is still giving same problems after unlock those files ?

Comment: Okay I had few ideas. First was to try short project path but I see You have already short paths. Second was to check out what strict errors You get. Does You project can run and install on device? If You delete `build` folder (on root and inside app folder!) it manually, can You build project and install on device? Check it out and let me know.

Answer (score 5):

you may not have permission to use the folder project try one of this solutions (maybe because of some antivirus apps or OS permissions):

1. copy project file to another place that you are sure to have read/write permission and open that new project folder in android studio
2. run android studio as administrator
3. right click on project folder and get read and write permissions to your username.

Comment: one virus always pop up when i restart and run my applications

Comment: **Could not delete path** problems arriving bcoz of that error ?

Comment: @sushildlh yes it could be the reason of your problem. add your project folder to antivirus scan exceptions or disable real time protection of your antivirus

Answer (score 2):

Most easy way to get unlock file.

1. Download [LOCKHUNTER](https://lockhunter.com/) and install in your system.
2. Close your android studio and select your Android studio from your system drive.
3. Select your folder, so you will get which all files is locked like image below.

[image]

4. Select all and Unlock BUTTON in application.
5. It will restart your application and have fun with android studio.